# Defining ImageView to be aligned right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Tried to align imageview to right.. code crashes. why?

UPDATED: Here is all row im having problem with. I think i failed on determining layouts somewhere here

```
    TableRow tableRow1 = new TableRow(this);
                tableRow1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                tl.addView(tableRow1);

                /* textView1 */
                TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
                textView1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParam

s.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                textView1.setText(names);

                tableRow1.addView(textView1);
                ImageView icon;
                icon = new ImageView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                icon.setLayoutParams(params);

                // icon.setLayoutParams(params);
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done); //default value
                switch (value) {
                case "1":
                    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done);
                    break;
                case "0":
                    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bad);
                default:
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("value : " + value);
                icon.setPadding(densityToPixels(13), 0, 0, 0);
                tableRow1.addView(icon);
```

Comment: Which error it shows and on which line? post logcat

Comment: params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT; this line

Comment: post your xml file. Which error it shows ?

Comment: i made it here in code this time

Comment: so there is no solution for this in code ? need to do it in xml ?

Answer (score 0):

try in xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/beam_contact_entry_contact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/beam_contact_entry_invite"
        android:background="?entry_background" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_info_avatar" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_entry_text"
                style="?primary_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Alexander Great"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_entry_text_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
                android:text="mobile"
                android:visibility="gone"
                style="?secondary_text"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/beam_contact_entry_invite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/beam_contact_entry_contact"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/beam_contact_entry_contact"
        android:background="?entry_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >   

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_entry_right_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="?entry_background"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sv_svyaznoy_contact" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you defined the `ImageView` dynamically like

```
ImageView icon = new ImageView(this);
```

then you are trying to get the `LayoutParam` through `icon.getLayoutParams();` which doesn't have any `LayoutPram` because you haven't set any.

To make it work replace

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)icon.getLayoutParams();
```

with

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
icon.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: if i replace code like here. i cant see picture anymore

Comment: @user3416113: post your `tableRow1` then.

Comment: @user3416113: As per your edited question I have edited my answer.